# How to type these old and rare Chinese characters?

Tags: characters, traditional-characters, old-chinese

I've tried to google these old Chinese characters using their closest approximations but still haven't found out any. I want to find these characters so that I can copy and paste them instead of taking photos of them every time needed. They are: [image] [image][image][image][image]

PS: I just added 3 more Old Chinese characters because before that I didn't have enough reputation to upload more than 2 images. So, at the beginning, there were 2 images but after adding 3 more, now there are 5 images.

Comment: 1. Zisea provides several methods besides 两分 for you to find characters, worth a try. 2. You can also use handwriting input methods.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**If you're having trouble displaying the following characters install the [Hanazono](http://www.fonts.jp/hanazono/) font**.

[zisea](http://zisea.com/zscontent.asp?uni=2C686)

> unicode码：2C686

[zisea](http://zisea.com/zscontent.asp?uni=29AC1)

> unicode码：29AC1
>
> 拼音mao4

`石 毛` doesn't seem to have much of a record as far as I can tell.

[image: oh]

> No results found for “⿱石毛”.

where `⿱` means top/bottom components in order of: 石(top) 毛(bottom)

`日` also doesn't seem to have an exact match that I can find, but [this](https://osdn.jp/projects/tsukurimashou/scm/svn/commits/555) website seems to say it's this:

[image: yes]

> ⿱日[T]

they say it's a combination of  `日` but the character looks more like 干 than 于, not sure if it will work for your purpose.

[zisea 肰](http://zisea.com/htm/80/80B0.htm)

> 肰
>
> unicode码：80B0

## How to find characters?

## 1

I used zisea's [两分](http://zisea.com/zslf.htm) to find both characters.

For the first one I searched `羽 能` (with a space in the middle)

[image: yeh]

and for the second I searched `高 毛` (with a space in the middle).

[image]

If you can figure out the two major components you can pretty much find any character you want, unicode or non-unicode.

## 2

笔顺

[zdic sou suo page](http://www.zdic.net/sousuo/) explains it like this:

> 请输入正确的笔顺编码：李→1234521
>
> 笔顺说明
>
> 笔顺名称   一（横）    丨（竖）    丿（撇）    丶（点）    乛（折）
>
> 笔顺编号   1   2   3   4   5
>
> 注:一（提）归为一（横），亅（竖钩）归为丨（竖），丶（捺）归为丶（点），各种折笔笔画归为一（折）——《现代汉语通用字笔顺规范》

for instance is 丶一丨フ一丨フ丨フ一ノ一一フ which equates to 41251252513115

if you search for this on [zdic](http://zdic.net) select 字典 and then 笔顺 you'll get something like this:

[image: hi]

## 3

google components

[" 日" google search](https://www.google.com.sg/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=xFpAVqv6MauE8Qe8zK3wAQ&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22%F0%A5%8E%BF%20%E6%97%A5%22)

[image: okay]

If you try an exact search (quoted) for the components you are looking for you might also find what you want. That's how I found  referenced as a combination of the two, obvious, components of your character.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer user3306356. But sometimes the [zisea's 两分](http://zisea.com/zslf.htm) cannot combine 2 characters with one element upside and another element downside like [This One](http://postimg.org/image/4ni08isql/) which is a combination between 石 (upside) and 毛 (downside). How can I choose what way the elements are combined ? such as upside-downside, leftside-rightside.

Comment: Moreover,  [this character](http://postimg.org/image/ukbol4we5/) seems to have 3 components, could the website combine 3 components ? and how to control the order of the components ?

Comment: the components of [this character](http://postimg.org/image/j990wrpj1/) doesn't seem to exist. How can I create its two components with the strokes and radicals table on [zisea's 两分](http://zisea.com/zslf.htm)? thanks.

Comment: @Einsteingen what are these characters exactly, even? Those other charterers I think you can find by searching 智 于 and 月 犬

Comment: they are Old Chinese characters found on bronze inscriptions of the state of Chu during the Warring States period.

Comment: I did search 智 于 but the resulting character is 智 with component 于 on the right instead of being on the top.

Comment: I think some of these might simply just not exist.

Comment: I'm not sure, therefore I've asked around how to type them. Do you know any other website that allows combining Chinese components and manipulating their order: left, right, up, down ?

Comment: @Einsteingen I've updated my answer to include as much information as I could.

Comment: Thanks very much for your high effort in helping me out,  user3306356. Though it does not provide all characters needed, but I'm thankful for your help. Your answer is accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I used [Wenlin](http://wenlin.com/) to find them:

```
 [mào]

(=能䏻竜) (!龍)
```

I required students to own a copy of Wenlin when I college classes on the Chinese script — it's a very useful program.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, brannerchinese. Could you tell me how to use Wenlin ? do I have to download it or something? What font should I use to display the character  ? it does not display properly. The character  is opposite to my desired one which is with 羽 upside and 能 downside, how can I reverse the order of its two components ?

Comment: Right! I didn't even notice the reversal —  is the character you want, and I myself don't have a font to display it. Sorry!

Wenlin is a wonderful tool, but you have to buy it.

Comment: You've added new characters?

Comment: If Wenlin doesn't help, I normally use the built-in Character Viewer, set to "Han Chinese Characters — All", and search by Kāngxī-system radical-plus-additional-strokes. That's a method that I think is too complicated to explain here. Regrets!

Comment: Yes, I just added 3 more characters because at the time I made this question, I did not have enough reputation to add more than 2 images of Old Chinese characters.

Comment: Let me try to help you off-line. Please add dot-com to my username and you should be able to find my email address. The Kāngxī-system radical-plus-additional-strokes requires learning the system, not something to be picked up in a few minutes.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether or not it is complicated. I'll google it to find out the way. But could the built-in Character Viewer run on Windows 7 or only MAC ? because I'm using Windows 7.

Comment: Thanks. How to "add dot-com" to your username ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [CiYang](http://www.ciyang.com). It's perfect for unusual characters. You can input those parts of the character separately, it will give the candidate characters for you, including very explicit explanation and usage if there is.

For example, you can input 月犬, it will show you 肰(ran2) with explanation and unicode.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I checked it out but 能+羽 and 石+毛 don't lead to any result.

Answer (score 0):

1. U+2C686  = ⿱羽能
2. U+29AC1  = ⿰高毛
3. ⿱石毛, not encoded, according to GlyphWiki, does not exist
4. ⿱⿰知于日, UTC-01586, GlyphWiki http://en.glyphwiki.org/wiki/utc-01586. Will U+2327B  suffice?
5. ⿰⺼犬, not encoded, according to GlyphWiki, does not exist.