# Help finding unicode code point for compound character 任鸟?

Tags: translation, characters, character-identification, software

I'd like to combine 任 as the upper part with 鸟 as the lower part. I was wondering if anyone would be able to help me to find the unicode character for this or help me type it on a mac computer. A guide for typing compound characters would be equally helpful. Thanks!

Comment: I wrote this old post years ago: https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/16469/4136 - similar points to lilysirius' but might have something else of help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

鵀 is actually an existing character in CJK Unified Ideographs (U+9D40), meaning *hoopoe* 戴胜鸟. But since it's not frequently used, the corresponding simplified character  is in 扩E：2CE0A.

There is an input method called 两分输入法 offered by 字海. The instruction for the input method is [here](http://cheonhyeong.com/File/LiangFenHandbook.pdf). Basically you type the character by the pinyin of two of its components.

You can directly install the [Windows version](http://cheonhyeong.com/File/ZiHaiLiangFenIME4.0_Setup.7z) or install the [rime scheme](http://cheonhyeong.com/File/ZHLF_rime_4.0.7z). In the latter case, it can be used across flatforms. You can follow the  [instructions](https://rime.im/download/) to install rime on Mac. There is also an [online solution](http://www.yedict.com/zslf.htm) where you can type the two components with whatever input method you want and search for the character.

Comment: Excellent, incredibly helpful answer!